# When Connected to Network Mongodb Uses my NIC Address?

Tags: mongodb, grails

I have a Grails app that I am hooking up to a MongoDB instance.  In my Datasource.groovy, I have the following declared:

```
grails {
    mongo {
        host = "localhost"
        port = 27017
        databaseName = "mmib-mongo"
    }
}
```

Mongo is installed and starts just fine.

The problem is that when I am connected to a network, using grails run-app logs the following exception:

Packaging Grails application.....
| Running Grails application

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

Configuring Spring Security LDAP ...
... finished configuring Spring Security LDAP
| Error 2012-11-19 15:42:16,428 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: can't call something : MBP-C02J91TWDKQ5.local/192.168.0.131:27017/mmib-mongo; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : MBP-C02J91TWDKQ5.local/192.168.0.131:27017/mmib-mongo
Message: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: can't call something : MBP-C02J91TWDKQ5.local**/**192.168.0.131:27017**/mmib-mongo**; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : MBP-C02J91TWDKQ5.local/192.168.0.131:27017/mmib-mongo

Any clue why when I'm connected to a network, Grails/Mongo wants to use that IP Address instead of localhost, which I verified is 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts

Comment: are there other lines in your /etc/hosts?  I'm guessing there may be a different hostname (MBP-C02J91TWDKQ5.local) further and that's probably what `hostname` is returning.

Comment: This is what I have in the hosts file.  It's a new machine with little updated.##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

Comment: that last entry is what's being used - this is a Mac, right?

Comment: It is.  Interestingly, MongoDB was installed using Homebrew.  I was a little suspicious, so I tried the binary instead, and there were no problems.  So it's a partial fix, but it doesn't explain why the Homebrew installed version has a problem with the .local domain...  So now the question is what configuration in MongoDB should be changed to accomodate this?

Comment: Oh, btw, the version that Mac Ports installs does not exhibit this behavior either.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew tells MongoDB to listen on only on 127.0.0.1, not your public interface or a ".local" hostname:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/mongodb.rb#L95

Try deleting the bind_ip line from your local copy of mongod.conf and simply protecting port 27017 with a firewall, or else change the "bind_ip" entry in mongod.conf.